# What is the rationale for computing a confidence interval in a study that won't or can't be repeated?

Tags: confidence-interval, population, replicability

As far as I understand it, when we compute a confidence interval (say a $95$% CI), we have confidence in the procedure, not in the current data we have (as a $95$% CI means that $95$% of confidence intervals computed for many other hypothetical samples will contain the true value in the population).

So just with the sample we collected, there is no way of knowing if the current interval we see includes the true value, even if the interval is very small.

So I was wondering: Is there a (scientific) rationale to compute a confidence interval in a study that won't or can't be repeated exactly? Or is it useless to compute a CI in this situation? I would also appreciate any reference or paper on this specific subject.

Comment: How would the confidence interval for your study become any more useful if the study *was* repeated?

Comment: On the long run, as we conduct more studies and compute more CIs, we'd get a better idea of the true value. How I see it, the value of the CI relies on being analyzed with other CIs. I may be wrong though, that's why I ask this question!

Comment: I agree with @GeorgeSavva .  In reality, very few studies will be repeated, at least, not exactly. The utility of a CI doesn't depend on the study being repeated, it is an answer to a hypothetical question. You could argue that CIs are not really useful (and many will say that Bayesian credible intervals are much more so), but that argument won't change if the study can be repeated or not.

Comment: In general, you are following a procedure that produces CIs that cover the true value 95% of the time. The CI from one sample may be one of the 95% that cover or one of the 5% that do not. That is the unavoidable uncertainty. Repeatability is unnecessary.(Switching to a Bayesian credible interval, for example, does not remove the uncertainty.)

Comment: I think I need some time for all that to sink in, but I really appreciate all the responses above. If someone has some further reading to suggest on this subject, I'd be thankful too. Also, I was wondering about Bayesian intervals too but didn't want to make my question too complicated, but anyway Graham Bornholt addresses it clearly. Thank you again.

Comment: @PeterFlom  +1 to the comment. I deem this could be a genuine answer to the query (if you wish).

Comment: No, switching to Bayesian thinking makes a big change here.  Think of a one-time event or an experiment that can never be repeated (e.g., in medicine because background therapies change).  Bayes attempts to uncover the data generating process for **the data at hand**.  The fact that frequentist statistics requires you to do the thought experiment that entails exact repeats of study designs/sampling process ultimately makes a confidence interval almost impossible to interpret.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Your "fact" is a common misconception about CIs promulgated by Bayesian adherents. There is no *requirement* for a "thought experiment that entails exact repeats..." (as my earlier comment demonstrates).

Comment: Then please define what 95% of the time means.

Comment: What would be the rationale in, say, choosing to undergo a surgical procedure that is known to be reliable in 95% of all cases, even though the procedure can be performed on you only once?  cc @FrankHarrell What makes this "impossible to interpret" from a Frequentist or decision-theoretic perspective?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Under the assumed model and prior to random sampling, we know that there is a 95% probability that the random CI will cover the true parameter. We also know that the observed CI from a single sample either does or does not cover the parameter. This has a variety of implications (not requirements!). For example, if a researcher employs 95% confidence interval procedures in a large number of independent studies then, under the various models, very probably approximately 95% of the CIs wil cover their true parameters.No repetitions required!

Comment: Not certain that helps the practitioner who has one dataset in front of her.  One thing I’m certain about: A Bayesian interpretation of a Bayesian uncertainty interval is far easier to understand and explain than a frequentist interpretation of a frequentist uncertainty interval.  Also once you bend estimates using shrinkage (penalized MLE) you lose the ability to get confidence intervals, whereas posterior distributions apply equally well with shrinkage priors as they do with traditional, wider priors.  Just as they do when incorporating extra-study data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quote from Larry Wasserman's book "All of statistics"$^{[1]}$ that offers a different perspective on the topic. On page 92, he writes:

> Some texts interpret confidence intervals as follows: if I repeat the
> experiment over and over, the interval will contain the parameter 95
> percent of the time. This is correct but useless since we rarely
> repeat the same experiment over and over. A better interpretation is
> this:
>
> > On day 1, you collect data and construct a 95 percent confidence
> > interval for a parameter $\theta_1$. On day 2, you collect new data
> > and construct a 95 percent confidence interval for an unrelated
> > parameter $\theta_2$. On day 3, you collect new data and construct a
> > 95 percent confidence interval for an unrelated parameter $\theta_3$-
> > You continue this way constructing confidence intervals for a sequence
> > of unrelated parameters $\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots$ Then 95 percent
> > of your intervals will trap the true parameter value. There is no need
> > to introduce the idea of repeating the same experiment over and over.

An example would be weather forecasts: Every day, the forecaster could present a confidence interval for the probability of rain. Because we never have the exact same conditions, the underlying parameter is different every day. On average, 95 out of 100 confidence intervals will trap the true parameter value.

I don't know if this helps with the interpretation of a particular interval but I find the perspective a refreshing alternative to the often-read "standard interpretation" referring to the repetition of the exact same experiment.

For some suggestions of how to interpret a concrete confidence interval, see the paper by Rafi & Greenland (2020)$^{[2]}$. Here is a relevant section of their paper:

> [...] we exploit the fact that a 95% CI summarizes the results of
> varying the test hypothesis H over a range of parameter values,
> displaying all values for which p > 0.05 [56] and hence s < 4.32 bits
> [31, 57]. Thus the CI contains a range of parameter values that are
> more compatible with the data than are values outside the interval,
> under the background assumptions [31, 46]. Unconditionally (and thus
> even if the background assumptions are uncertain), the interval shows
> the values of the parameter which, when combined with the background
> assumptions, produce a test model that is “highly compatible” with the
> data in the sense of having less than 4.32 bits of information against
> it. We thus refer to CI as compatibility intervals rather than
> confidence intervals [30, 31, 57]; their abbreviation remains "CI."

**References**

$[1]$ Wasserman, L. (2004). All of statistics: a concise course in statistical inference. Springer Science & Business Media.

$[2]$ Rafi, Z., & Greenland, S. (2020). Semantic and cognitive tools to aid statistical science: replace confidence and significance by compatibility and surprise. BMC medical research methodology, 20, 1-13. ([link](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12874-020-01105-9))

Comment: It's probably helpful, but I just can't tell what it actually means.  Why would I compare parameters that have different meanings?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think the rationale here:

> Is there a (scientific) rationale to compute a confidence interval in a study that won't or can't be repeated exactly?

Makes it *more* necessary that the CI is computed. If the likelihood of a replication of the study is extremely low, having a CI estimate will help others know what a plausible range of the statistical estimate is when replication is either close to impossible or completely impossible.

Consider for example a study of those with a rare brain injury which only occurs to about 5 people per year. A sample of only three patients would be super informative if they are already hard to find. Say someone runs a study on the patients and finds a considerably narrow range in the CI lower/upper bounds. Because of the difficulty in running another study like it, others do not try to replicate this study.

Because they have a well-informed estimate of what a plausible point value could be, they can already infer what it *should* be in the population.

##### Edit

I should add that one would have to be very mindful of the limitations of a single study's CIs, particularly if they are strongly built around the idiosyncrasies of that dataset, which may not extrapolate well to other datasets. A reported CI is of course better than none, particularly when the research, as highlighted above, is difficult to do. But it is important to note that a single CI has it's limitations.

What may be a good alternative in this case is something like a Bayesian credible interval, which may be better if one assigns informative priors around what a population value should be. This is because you would at least be able to constrain the estimate to certain values that match what one should expect in reality.

Comment: I voted for the other answer because it mentions some papers, but I just wanted to thank you for your answer that I've found very helpful too (unfortunately it looks like I can't vote for it too).

Comment: No worries! Glad you found both useful.

Comment: Exactly how does a single confidence limit inform you of plausible unknown values of the parameter?

Comment: See edit above.